# Server side rendering with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, server-side-rendering

Recently Im struggling with enabling server side rendering with Firebase. I was following David East tutorial on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82tZAPMHfT4&t=607s aswell as his github repo with that project: https://github.com/davideast/react-ssr-firebase-hosting

However, the github repo is slightly different than the app he made on youtube so it may cause some confusions :/

Anyways, my issue is that Im missing some little part to this whole puzzle.

So **first of all**, my app has following structure:

```
- app
  -- index.html
  -- rest of files, store, app.js etc
  -- all folders with components etc
- functions (google cloud functions)
  -- index.js (holding my functions and code responsible for the SSR)
  -- app (every file of my app compiled by babel, so I can render it to string)
  -- package.json
  -- node_modules
```

Okey, so the most important file - `index.js` which holds my code responsible for SSR + some custom google cloud functions:

### **`index.js`**:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import App from './app/containers/App';

const index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');

const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<App />);
  const finalHtml = index.replace('app', html);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(finalHtml);
});

export const ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);

exports.someCustomFunction1 = functions.database.ref(...).onWrite(...);
exports.someCustomFunction2 = functions.database.ref(...).onWrite(...);
```

The code should be just fine... it's almost identical as it is in official Firebase tutorial regarding SSR.

### **`index.html`** (nothing special):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">app</div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here comes my **first question**:

If I now use `firebase deploy --only functions` it says, that `index.html` was not found - and it's obvious, since **there's no** `index.html` inside `functions` folder.

**However**, if I change the path to:

`fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../build/index.html', 'utf8');` - and that's the actual place where `index.html` is after the build process, then Im calling once again `firebase deploy --only functions` and another error appears:

```
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/user_code
/../build/index.html'
```

[image]

But what's that `user_code` and wheres does it come from?

## Some final conclusion

If I remove that part responsible for reading (fs) the `index.html` file, so then it looks like:

```
app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<App />);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(html);
});
```

#### Then it seems to work fine!

For first second only text `app` appears while page is loading and then the whole page loads, so it seems that the function itself works fine (as you can see in my `index.html` file, there's only `app` text as content in my `root div`. (server response seems to work fine, but thats all, actually)

## Final question (once again)

What should I do with my `index.html` file reading or where should I move it so the console doesnt throw any error while deploying the functions?

Sorry for such a long post. Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: You'll need to move your `app` directory to be a child of your `functions` directory -- when you deploy your functions only the functions directory is built into the runtime, so you need *all* files that need to be accessible from functions inside that directory.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Firstly thank you so much for your reply. Secondly - following David East's tutorial, I've compiled my whole app with Babel and placed it inside `/functions` directory. And it is there, actually. So I think that's not the case right now.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Anyways - my problem right now is where to place `index.html` file. The directory which is compiled by Babel inside `/functions` doesn't contain `index.html` file so I have to take it from... `/build` directory? Or that `index.html` should be placed somewhere else?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @SergeAlmazov Yes. I removed firebase from my application.

Comment: @Patrickkx Why? What do you use instead of Firebase?

Comment: @SergeAlmazov Firebase isn't flexible. I didnt like it. It's pretty difficult to use firebase together with e.g. redux. I decided to learn new stuff and I wrote my api in nodejs instead. What's more - firebase belongs to Google, and to be honest I don't like anything what is connected with them :(

Comment: You just simply need to remove index.html from build and place it in functions folder. Explained here too https://medium.com/@antonybudianto/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-firebase-functions-cd67fdb2b605

Comment: Any examples to demonstrate on how to include css and images?